# Find $\lim \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^{p-1}}{n^p}$

Tags: limits

Find $\lim \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^{p-1}}{n^{p}}$

- It is not hard to figure it is  $\frac{1}{p}$.

I can prove $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^{p-1}}{n^p}$ is larger than $\frac{1}{p}$  but i can prove it's limitation is $\frac{1}{p}$

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

Recall the Riemann sum of the integral

$$\int_0^1x^{p-1}\,dx=\frac{1}{p}$$

**SPOLIER ALERT: SCROLL OVER SHADED AREA TO REVEAL THE SOLUTION**

> The right-hand side Riemann sum for the integral $\int_0^1x^p\,dx$ is given by $$\int_0^1x^{p-1}\,dx=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{p-1}\frac{1}{n}$$This can be seen by partitioning the interval $[0,1]$ into equal size subintervals of length $1/n$.  The right-hand side of the $k$'th subinterval is $x_k=k/n$.  Thus, the sum that approximates the integral is $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{p-1}\frac{1}{n}$$Passing to the limit we obtain $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{p-1}\frac{1}{n}=\int_0^1x^{p-1}\,dx=\frac1p$$as was to be shown!